# Microsoft Unity IoC does not work and ASP.NET mvc4 application. Why?

Tags: asp.net, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

I'm trying to set up Unity IoC container to ASP.NET mvc4 application. 
I created empty project and using package management console installed next products

- Install-Package Unity
- Install-Package Unity.Mvc4

Everything finished successfully. But after I run my application I have exception

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
>   Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Cannot create an instance of an interface.

Here is simple code. 
Global.asax.cs

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        Bootstrapper.Initialise();
    }
}

public interface IA
{
    void test();
}
public class A : IA
{
    public A() { }
    public void test()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index(IA a)
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

Bootstrapper.cs:

```
public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static void Initialise()
    {
        var container = BuildUnityContainer();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
    }

    private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IA, A>();          

        return container;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong and why code does not work?

Stack trace:

> Stack Trace: [MissingMethodException: Cannot create an instance of an interface.]
>      System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>      System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +98
>      System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +241
>      System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +69
>      System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +199
>      System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +572
>      System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +454
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +317
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +117
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass25.b*_1e(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +476
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +124
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +304
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__17(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +30
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +124
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +389
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +124
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +319
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +15
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +76
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +124
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +251
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8837208
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184

Comment: Please supply the stack trace.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about it. Done

Comment: i think you need to create an instance in the controller. see my answer it may help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I exactly don't know what's wrong with yours but here is the settings that works for me;

```
public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static void Initialise()
    {
        var container = BuildUnityContainer();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
    }

    private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<ICategoryRepository, CategoryRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        return container;
    }
}
```

Global.asax

```
 Bootstrapper.Initialise();
```

now, in my controller constructor;

```
ICategoryRepository _catRepo;

public CategoryController(ICategoryRepository catRepo)
{
    _catRepo = catRepo;
}
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.CategoriesList = _catRepo.GetAllCategories();
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I put interface to action instead controller constructor. It seems that I need some relax :) thanks a lot for help